# Probability of hitting X shots in N tries knowing that the P(hit) is the ratio of previous hits

Tags: bayesian, inference

Let $X$ be the number of hits in $N$ tries, I know that the probability of the next hit is $P(\text{Hit}) =X/N$.

How can I get the generic expression for the probability distribution function of hitting $x$ hits in $N$ tries, knowing that the probability of hitting the first shot is $p_1$?

I've been trying to find the solution to this, I know from brute forcing that for $p_1 = 0.5$ the distribution is a constant ( $1/(N+1)$ I believe), when it's higher than 0.5 it's a positive slope line and lower than 0.5 a negative slope line. I just don't know how to mathematically reach a result.

Edit: Clarification.
Let's assume the first two 6 shots are known. There were 3 hits and 3 misses, and so the probability of the 7th shot hitting is 0.5. Should that hit, the probability of hitting the 8th shot would be $4/7$. Should that miss, the probability of hitting the 8th shot would be $3/7$.

I forgot to say that when I was brute forcing I assumed the first two shots to be a hit and a miss, but knowing any sequence of two or more previous shots would be necessary for the problem to make sense.

Comment: The nature of this question is obscure. On what basis do you "know" the probability of the next hit?  That would be the case only in the very rare circumstance that the number of hits in those $N$ tries happened to be exactly $P(\text{Hit})N.$

Comment: Doesn't everything comes down to either the first try is a hit or not? If it's a hit then the probability of a hit on the second try will be 1 and so on, and if not then the probabilities of the next tries are 0? That is $P(X = N) = 1-P(X=0) = p_1$ and $P(X=x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0,1$? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Added clarification to the initial post. Assume the 6 shots are known.

Comment: It's not hard to write a recurrence relation. Solving such might require digging up some methods I've long forgotten...

Comment: My last comment comes from a perspective that this is a toy problem where you're declaring the probability given the past, whereas others question how such a probability can exist (or be known); perhaps the bayesian tag leads more toward the latter questioning?

Answer (score 0):

"There were 3 hits and 3 misses, and so the probability of the 7th shot hitting is 0.5. " Do you mean: "There were 3 hits and 3 misses, and so *my estimate of* the probability of the 7th shot hitting is 0.5. "

Some more information is needed before your question can be answered. Firstly, is the process stable? i.e. is the real probability of a hit constant, or does it drift over time?

Secondly, what prior knowledge do you have of the process? If you can encode your prior knowledge as a probability distribution of the unknown P then bayesian methods provide a precise answer to your question.

In the absence of prior knowledge your question has no answer. Put it this way: suppose I have already planned the infinite sequence miss, miss, hit, hit, miss, hit, miss ... according to some whim, then the first $n$ results don't really tell you anything about the $n+1^{st}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x, N)$ denote the probability given $N$ throws of making exactly $x$ of them.
We have

$$P(x, N+1) = P(x-1, N)\cdot\frac{x-1}{N} + P(x, N)\cdot\frac{N-x}{N}.$$

---

Starting from $P(x, 6)=\mathbb{I}(x=3)$ as you suggest:

Note that $P(2, N)=0$ for all $N$.  Using the recurrence,
$P(3, N+1)=0+P(3,N)\cdot\frac{N-3}{N}$, and so
$P(3, N) = 1 \frac36 \frac47\frac58\frac69\dotsb\frac{N-4}{N-1}=\frac{60}{(N-3)(N-2)(N-1)}$.  I don't particularly imagine there's a great closed-form for the general term.

---

Starting from $P(x, 2)=\begin{cases}a,&\text{x=0}\\b,&\text{x=1}\\c,&\text{x=2}\end{cases}$:

I didn't carefully state the recurrence for small values, but it's not hard to see that $P(0, N)=a$ and $P(N, N)=c$ for all $N$.  Then it turns out that $P(x, N)=b/(N-1)$ for all $x\in(0, N)$, the uniform distribution you suggested earlier (especially taking $a=c=0$).  This is nice enough that there ought to be a slick proof, but I don't have it yet.  It can be proved in a not-so-slick way by doing the computation for $P(1, N)$, $P(N-1, N)$, and the rest of the cases separately.